# Morphia: Saving document in a specific collection

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using Morphia 2.x, and I have a usecase where i want to save 1 Entity class into 2 different Collections.
However Morphia 2.x `save` method doesn't have any option to pass a Collection Name, Where as Morphia 1.x had this option.
I am not sure why they have removed this option.

```
@Entity
public class Unit {
    @Id
    private String id;
    protected Unit() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Morphia 2.3 will [reintroduce](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.2/javadoc/dev/morphia/Datastore.html#save(T,dev.morphia.InsertOneOptions)) this functionality as an option passed via the `alternateCollection` option on `InsertOneOptions` (among other options classes).  I'm working to get this out soon.